# XSLT rename parent element with value of specific child

Tags: xslt

I would like to rename parent property element with value of specific child (property + key)
Tried different ways of XSLT, but cant make it working so far..

Input:

```
<Root>
    <Row>
        <ID>1913</ID>
        <Data>
            <Property>
                <Key>1</Key>
            </Property>
            <Property>
                <Key>2</Key>
            </Property>
        </Data>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Expected output:

```
<Root>
    <Row>
        <ID>1913</ID>
        <Data>
            <Property1>
                <Key>1</Key>
            </Property1>
            <Property2>
                <Key>2</Key>
            </Property2>
        </Data>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

XSLT part:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="Data/Property">
                <xsl:variable name="property"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$key}">
                <xsl:value-of select=key"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Property">
    <xsl:element name="Property{Key}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course this assumes that the concatenation of `"Property"` and the value of `Key` is a valid XML element name.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, very clear xslt and it is working as well.